# list column name order by column id without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns table_num, id in my table called medium

I want to echo table_num without duplicates based on the sequence of id by DESC.

I am getting results 4,2,7,5,3 with this query but the results i want is 4,5,7,2,3

[check this image for tables structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1dRl.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_num FROM medium ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: instead of image please provide sample data Ajay answers will get more accurate

Comment: when i use ASC my output is 35724 but i needed 4,5,7,2,3 based on id

Comment: First, DISTINCT will be executed and  the values with id 14 and 15 are removed. Then order by will be executed and thats why you are getting 4,2,7,5,3 instead of 4,5,7,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

The order you describe is **ascending**, not **descending**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_num FROM medium ORDER BY id ASC
-- Here ------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: when i use ASC my output is 35724 but i needed 4,5,7,2,3 based on id

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`, sort by each table_num's maximum id in descending order:

```
select table_num
from medium
group by table_num
order by max(id) desc
```

To better understand how it works, add `max(id)` to the select list:

```
select table_num, max(id) as max_id
from medium
group by table_num
order by max_id desc
```

Comment: please check the question again I have modified output to 4,5,7,2,3

Comment: The ORDER BY is now adjusted, to fit the new requirements.

Comment: yes i got it Thank you ...can you please explain..so that i can learn